Assigning probabilities to a graph.
I get that when it comes to random graphs we usually assume a random process that generates the graph in the first place with some probabilities, but I am trying to put the cart before the horse. Say in my hypothetical and dynamic world, there is no determinism, that is, whenever we take a paper and pencil to draw a graph there is an underlying probability in which we make the graph "appear". We somehow made the graph adding edges each time and forgot the probabilities.
Suppose we have a graph with $k$ edges, as a null model, we could always assign a probability of each edge appearing with a probability $1/k$ and a probability of each vertex appearing as a sum of probabilities of each edge adjacent to it (since a vertex could appear if any of the adjacent edges appear), right? Viewed this way can we make any graph as a random graph? I realize the sum of the probabilities of the nodes will not sum to one, but we could always scale them so the resulting sum is $1$.
If so, can we also compute the conditional probability $P(v_q|u_p)$ and $P(u_p|v_q)$ where $u_p$ and $v_q$ are adjacent vertices with probabilities $p$ and $q$? Especially using a contingency table with $u_p$, $\neg u_p$, $v_q$ and $\neg v_q$?

You're describing a structure where edges could exist without vertices. That is not a graph. Are you familiar with the random graph model $G(n, p) $?

Not really, if there is an edge, it will also induce a probability on the existence of the vertices. For example, lets say, we just have an edge, then the probability of that edge will be 1 and so will be the probability of the vertices. If we add another edge adjacent to the edge, then the vertex with two edges will have the probability 1 and the other vertices and edges will have a probability 1/2. If we add an edge that is not adjacent, then all the vertices and edges will have probability 1/2.
Yes, I am familiar with random graphs.

With independent probabilities, you still get the problem that with probability $1/4$, you create the edge, but not the vertex that it needs as an endpoint.

I don't understand where does the probability 1/4 come from?

You are given the edge a $\frac12$ probability of existing, and you are also giving one of its endpoints a $\frac12$ probability of existing. With probability $\frac12 (1 - \frac12)$, the first event happens and the second does not.

What do you mean? The second event happens as well. The edges could be adjacent or not. Which case are you referring to - adjacent or not adjacent?

I don't understand what you mean by edges being adjacent. Adjacency is a relationship between vertices. (But let me clarify what I mean. You describe a "null model" with vertices $x,y,z$ and edges $xy,yz$ where edges $xy,yz$ have a $\frac12$ probability of existing, and vertices $x,z$ have a $\frac12$ probability of existing. Then what happens if $xy$ is determined to exist, but $x$ is determined not to exist?)

It's possible that your answer is "this doesn't happen, because the events are not independent", but then your model is under-specified, because you have not described what the dependence is.

Ok, I should clarify, by adjacent edges, I mean they share a vertex. So there are two cases when the edge $xy$ exists: either an edge $yz$ appears, in which case the vertex $y$ will have the probability of $1$ and the rest having the probability of $1/2$ or a new edge $uv$ appears with all four vertices and two edges having probability of $1/2$

You're not really answering my question. When edge $xy$ exists, what does it mean for vertex $x$ to have probability $\frac12$? Does it mean that half the time that edge $xy$ exists, its endpoint $x$ does not?

It means $x$ has as much probability to appear as the edge joining $x$ and $y$ which has the probability of appearing $1/2$ of the time when we consider all edges in the system.

But we've already decided that edge $xy$ has appeared. What is the probability now? And under what circumstances does a vertex appear if none of the edges appear? And if edges $xy$ and $yz$ are potential edges that can appear, what is the conditional probability of $yz$ appearing, given that $xy$ has appeared? These are all questions that you're just refusing to answer, which makes you problem under-specified.
